# Check if replacement string is valid

Tags: java, regex, replace

This is my utility method to check if a [replacement string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) is valid:

```
public static boolean isValidReplacementString(String regex, String replacement) {
    try {
        "".replaceFirst(regex, replacement);
        return true;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | NullPointerException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'd like to check this before executing the real replacement because getting the source string(s) is expensive (I/O).

I find this solution quite hacky. Is there already a method in the standard library I am missing?

---

**Edit:**
[As pointed out by sln](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39089652/check-if-replacement-string-is-valid#comment65527171_39089652), this doesn't even work if no match is found.

---

**Edit:**
[Following shmosel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39089652/check-if-replacement-string-is-valid#39089966), I came up with this "solution":

```
private static boolean isLower(char c) {
    return c >= 'a' && c <= 'z';
}

private static boolean isUpper(char c) {
    return c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z';
}

private static boolean isDigit(char c) {
    return isDigit(c - '0');
}

private static boolean isDigit(int c) {
    return c >= 0 && c <= 9;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void checkRegexAndReplacement(String regex, String replacement)  {
    Pattern parentPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Map<String, Integer> namedGroups;
    int capturingGroupCount;

    try {
        Field namedGroupsField = Pattern.class.getDeclaredField("namedGroups");
        namedGroupsField.setAccessible(true);
        namedGroups = (Map<String, Integer>) namedGroupsField.get(parentPattern);
        Field capturingGroupCountField = Pattern.class.getDeclaredField("capturingGroupCount");
        capturingGroupCountField.setAccessible(true);
        capturingGroupCount = capturingGroupCountField.getInt(parentPattern);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("That's what you get for using reflection!", e);
    }

    int groupCount = capturingGroupCount - 1;

    // Process substitution string to replace group references with groups
    int cursor = 0;

    while (cursor < replacement.length()) {
        char nextChar = replacement.charAt(cursor);
        if (nextChar == '\\') {
            cursor++;
            if (cursor == replacement.length())
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "character to be escaped is missing");
            nextChar = replacement.charAt(cursor);
            cursor++;
        } else if (nextChar == '$') {
            // Skip past $
            cursor++;
            // Throw IAE if this "$" is the last character in replacement
            if (cursor == replacement.length())
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Illegal group reference: group index is missing");
            nextChar = replacement.charAt(cursor);
            int refNum = -1;
            if (nextChar == '{') {
                cursor++;
                StringBuilder gsb = new StringBuilder();
                while (cursor < replacement.length()) {
                    nextChar = replacement.charAt(cursor);
                    if (isLower(nextChar) ||
                            isUpper(nextChar) ||
                            isDigit(nextChar)) {
                        gsb.append(nextChar);
                        cursor++;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (gsb.length() == 0)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                            "named capturing group has 0 length name");
                if (nextChar != '}')
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                            "named capturing group is missing trailing '}'");
                String gname = gsb.toString();
                if (isDigit(gname.charAt(0)))
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                            "capturing group name {" + gname +
                                    "} starts with digit character");
                if (namedGroups == null || !namedGroups.containsKey(gname))
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                            "No group with name {" + gname + "}");
                refNum = namedGroups.get(gname);
                cursor++;
            } else {
                // The first number is always a group
                refNum = (int)nextChar - '0';
                if (!isDigit(refNum))
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                            "Illegal group reference");
                cursor++;
                // Capture the largest legal group string
                boolean done = false;
                while (!done) {
                    if (cursor >= replacement.length()) {
                        break;
                    }
                    int nextDigit = replacement.charAt(cursor) - '0';
                    if (!isDigit(nextDigit)) { // not a number
                        break;
                    }
                    int newRefNum = (refNum * 10) + nextDigit;
                    if (groupCount < newRefNum) {
                        done = true;
                    } else {
                        refNum = newRefNum;
                        cursor++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (refNum < 0 || refNum > groupCount) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("No group " + refNum);
            }
        } else {
            cursor++;
        }
    }
}
```

If this method throws, either the regex or the replacement string is invalid.

This is even stricter than `replaceAll` or `replaceFirst` because these methods won't call `appendReplacement` if no match is found, hence "missing" invalid group references.

Comment: I'm not sure that the engine will check the replacement string if there isn't a match, I could be wrong. That being said, some errors at the time of replacement could be invalid capture group backreference not defined in the regex.

Comment: Use apache StringUtils.isNotNull method to check for null before replacing.

Comment: @sln You're right. `isValidReplacementString("test", "$")` is returning `true` because no match is found. So my method doesn't even work correctly.

Comment: @amitmah Checking for `null` is only a minor aspect. This is more about the syntax and the semantics (e.g. referring to a non-existent capturing group).

Comment: What syntax check is needed for java's String.replace method?

Comment: @amitmah Well, you could read OPs link ...

Comment: @Tom, thanks i did't saw the link earlier, as per the API doc, the method does not throw any error it seems , 
public String replaceFirst(String replacement)

Comment: @AndyTurner But how do I do that without the source string?

Comment: @xehpuk can you give an example where you get exception for replacement string.

Comment: @amitmah `"".replaceFirst("", "$")`

Comment: What do you mean by a "valid replacement string"?

Comment: It is not possible to have use a string without having a string. If looking for a delayed read, a lambda would work - but the string would still need to be read *before* use.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Having correct syntax and not referring to non-existent capturing groups.

Comment: @xehpuk you can restrict the replacement string to alphanumeric for example:
 Pattern p= Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*");
Matcher m= p.matcher("asdfasdf12341234");
if(m.matches()) { ....}

Comment: @amitmah Why would I restrict the replacement string?

Comment: You need to replace to avoid the IllegalAccessException, and catch the exception early, as you mentioned that the string update is time consuming

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your best bet is to copy the process implemented in [`Matcher.appendReplacement()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/regex/Matcher.java#Matcher.appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer%2Cjava.lang.String%29), cutting out any logic pertaining to the source string or the result string. This inevitably means you won't be able to do certain validations, such as validating group names and indexes, but you should be able to apply most of them.

Comment: I've taken the body of `appendReplacement` and made it runnable (edit in the question). Contrary to your expectation, this now is even stricter, also throwing if no match is found. This is probably the best it can get.

Comment: @xehpuk You're right, I confused the source string with the regex.